# return content section as json in wp rest api v1

Tags: json, wp-api

I am using WP REST API.
I want to get the posts from my blog and show them in my android app.
So, everything is OK, but i need to ask a question to make sure about something:
when i call posts in the content section; there is a lots of HTML tag, is there any way (another plugin or ... ) which return this part (or any part witch have HTML elements) as JSON or some how make it easier and separate the HTML tags?
I am using HTML to java Parser but i just want to make sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and you should) always filter the output of WP_REST_API.

```
add_filter('json_prepare_post', 'change_this_into_a_proper_function_name', 999);
function change_this_into_a_proper_function_name($post){
    // hack and slash into your $post here. This is a regular WP_Post
    // add custom fields and tax terms you might need, remove what
    // you don't want to expose to app or are never going to need...
    // This filtering step is actually a must imho, as it really influences
    // the speed at which your posts will load over poor connections.
    // Special care should be taken with attachments, I usually replace them
    // with versions of 800px width (or even 600) for both Android and IoS.
    return $post;
}
```

The only app where I didn't completely remove `$post->content` in favor of the excerpt was an app for a bookstore, where users were installing the app specifically to read book reviews. But even there, when pulling lists of reviews I was filtering the content out and only loaded it fully only on `read more`. It payed off. The app stayed agile even on poorly resourced devices.